# How to import typescript module from interactive console in intellij

Tags: javascript, angular, intellij-idea

I come from vanilla JavaScript, and I just don't get this. Usually I work directly from the interactive console in chrome or firefox and I can access all my resources to try them out manually.

Right now I have an Angular project with Intellij and I want to try out code inside a module. To be specific I'm busy implementing a queue pattern. So I made a `Queue` class.

When I type in the name of my class inside the javascript console, Intellij finds it as a suggestion. When I use their suggestion it inserts the import statement like `import {Queue} from "./Queue";`.

But when I try this it spews `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Which I understand, but how can I import the module from the console? (I figure that there is a compiled .js file somewhere, which I can import, right!?).

[image]

Comment: I guess you could do something like `window.queue = Queue;` inside your module to make the class accessible to the console. Haven't tried it.

Comment: In browser that works, in Intellij it does not :(. It would be nice if there was a way which does not require me to add `window.[name] = [class]` to all the classes I want to try.

Comment: I don't think there is though. Looks like you need write unit tests instead.

Comment: doesn't seem to be possible with Typescript modules bundled with webpack. Doesn't work for me in Chrome Dev Tools console either